Package installed from test.pypi.org is not the same folder structure as was uploaded to the repository
I created a package and uploaded it to test.pypi.org: https://test.pypi.org/project/name-generator-nicomp/0.0.2/
The logic reads a text file that I want to include in the package. In my initial design I put the text file in its' own folder and my logic ran just fine on my local machine.
I installed the package from test.pypi.org onto a different computer using pip:
python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ name-generator-nicomp --upgrade

Then, I run this script:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from name_generator_nicomp.NameGenerator import NameGenerator
    nameGenerator = NameGenerator()

and it fails inside the package code on this line:
    with importlib.resources.open_text("src.data", self.noun_file) as my_file:

The error is:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Looking in the .gz file created by the build script, the src folder is there and the data folder is inside it. The repo on test.pypi.org also has the folder structure in it. It can be downloaded and verified here: https://test.pypi.org/project/name-generator-nicomp/0.0.2/#files
However, when I look at the installation of the package on my local machine, all the files (code and data) are in one folder and there are no other folders at all.
My .toml file is
[project]
name = "name_generator_nicomp"
version = "0.0.2"
authors = [
  { name="xxx xxxxxx", email="xxx.com" },
]
description = "Some description."
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://github.com/nicomp42/name_generator"
Issues = "https://github.com/nicomp42/name_generator/issues"

[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

The entire traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nicholdw\eclipse-workspace\myNameGenerator\mainPackage\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    nameGenerator = NameGenerator()
  File "C:\Users\nicholdw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\name_generator_nicomp\NameGenerator.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.prepare()
  File "C:\Users\nicholdw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\name_generator_nicomp\NameGenerator.py", line 47, in prepare
    with importlib.resources.open_text("src.data", self.noun_file) as my_file:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\resources.py", line 82, in open_text
    open_binary(package, resource), encoding=encoding, errors=errors
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\resources.py", line 43, in open_binary
    package = _common.get_package(package)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 66, in get_package
    resolved = resolve(package)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 57, in resolve
    return cand if isinstance(cand, types.ModuleType) else importlib.import_module(cand)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'


What’s the structure of the project? Are the module at the project-name/src/module-name/data?

@TimurU You can see the structure of the project at the repo address I provided. The code is not in the data folder, rather it is in a different folder at the same level. BUT when the package installs on my local machine all the files are in the same folder.


Its need to add package data information to pyproject.toml:

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["*.txt"]


When you're calling data at NameGenerator.py:

with importlib.resources.open_text("src.data", "nouns.txt") as my_file:

it wrong, because src is a src-like source python folder, but not the package!
This is returning an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

You're set three packages: data, main, name_generator_nicomp.
There is its need to invoke the package by name.
In your case its data.
I think the best way is:
import name_generator_nicomp

. . . 

with importlib.resources.open_text("name_generator_nicomp.data", "nouns.txt") as my_file:


There is the excellent documentation:


Data Files Support
Package Discovery and Namespace Packages

There a lot samples to any situations.
Good luck with your work!!!

I made the changes you suggest:
I  changed the code to
with importlib.resources.open_text("data", "nouns.txt") as my_file:
I added the entries to the .toml file.
and it still installs the package from the PyPi with no folder structure and all the code files are together with the data files. No change.

Oh.. 1) sub package data inside package name_generator_nicomp, I’m editing. 2) sub package main is not good idea. It’s reserved word. I think it’s need to remove folder src/main

In my case I m putting data folder inside module (not as another module)

I renamed that folder. No change in behavior.

I think this is a case of me not knowing how to tell pip what to install and what to ignore and/or how to configure the package that's downloaded from pypi.

Try this: 1) change prof name: name_generator_nicomp —> NameGenerator (main module folder name) 2) remove main folder 3) move data folder to the NameGenerator folder 4) remove init py from data folder

Then you will get single module package NameGenerator.
